# Should I be nesting async.mapSeries in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to loop through cells in a matrix.

Each cell has a request associated with it, and I must wait for each request to finish before moving onto the next.

I currently use async.mapSeries to loop through the rows for **one of the columns**, like this.

```
    var columns = [1,2,3, ..., N];
    column = columns[0];

    function rowIterator(row, done){
        // Do something with the column's row (i.e. cell) value
            var bla = column * row
    }

    async.mapSeries(selectedRows, rowIterator, function (err, results){
        if(err){ 
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            // Do stuff
            console.log('All async requests successful');
        }
    });
```

However, imagine I wanted to perform the above but looping over another N columns .

If I was using normal forEach style loops, I would nest one inside the other. What is the correct way to achieve this with async.mapSeries. Should I be nesting these inside one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can nest these. You probably can just use `async.series` unless you really need the array that is the result of the `mapSeries` call. From your question, it seems like you don't actually need `mapSeries`, just `series`.

Comment: Ok, and would you recommend using async as opposed to something like promises (Q) for this?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not familiar with Q. The closest thing I can find is Q.all but that doesn't seem to guarantee execution in determined, serial order.